# Submit button reloads the page

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, button

I am working on a login form, and I am getting a strange behavior whereby whenever I click on the 'Login' button, the page simply reloads, without logging in my email and password through the 'submitHandler' function.
Below is a code of the form (I removed a lot of extra CSS formatting and div's).
Here is a screenshot of the form:

[loginForm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1BApL.png)

```
import React from 'react'
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { login } from "../../../actions/userActions";
import { Form, Button, Row, Col } from "react-bootstrap";

function LoginForm ({history}) {

    const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
    const [password, setPassword] = useState("");

    const submitHandler = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      console.log(email, password)
      // dispatch(login(email, password));
    };

   
    return (
       <form>              
              <button onSubmit={submitHandler} type="submit">
            Login
          </button>              
              </form>
 
    )
}

export default LoginForm
```

Does anyone have idea why the page reloads after clicking on the login button?

Comment: your handler must be on the form not on the button

Comment: You don't necessarily even need the `form` element or `type="submit" which means you don't need `preventDefault` either. `input` and `button` elements can exist with `form`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Issue

The button is of `type="submit"` but the form has no `onSubmit` handler and is thus taking the default form action, i.e. submitting the form and reloading the page.

## Solution

Move the `onSubmit` to the `form` element so the callback can prevent the default form action from occurring.

```
<form onSubmit={submitHandler}>              
  <button type="submit">
    Login
  </button>              
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also convert button `type=""` method provider `submit` to `button`, in some cases you don't really want to submit internal form so just keep in mind.

Here is the example,

```
<form>    
  <button onSubmit={submitHandler} type="button">
</form>
```

Other answer is also OK, but I would like to approach from a different angle.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling the submitHandler with onSubmit on the form instead of on the button.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).